# Add convex effect to image programmatically

Tags: c, algorithm, image-processing, effects

I am looking for some algorithms to add a convex mirror effect and concave mirror effect to an image. I want to know also how to make this efficiently: applying the algorithm to image data or overlay it by a transparent image that contains the effect. But I don't think the second choice is applicable in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing it manually instead of using hardware primitives, then the `bresenham interpolation algorithm` (usually used for line drawing) is the way to go: error propagation is far more efficient than other, more complex, methods.

What Bresenham does is just interpolation. Don't miss the opportunity to use its efficient design elsewhere (slope calculation for line-drwaing is just one of the many applications of interpolation: you can interpolate another dimension: 2D, 3D, transparency, reflection, colors, etc.).

25 years ago, I remember having used it to resize bitmaps and even do texture mapping in a real-time 3D engine! That was at a time graphic-accelerated video boards costed a fortune...

Comment: You should explain how such algorithm can be applied in requested case. Given that lens image deformation are generally obtained from a bidimensional Fourier transform, obtaining such complex effect with one of the simplest algorithms known would be amazing.

Comment: Let's consider 1D (a scanline), because the 2D problem is resolved by 2 passes (one hozizontal, one vertical). So, a concave effect will enlarge the center segment of the scanline and stretch the border segments (and you can take advantage of the symmetry to only calculate half the values). That's what interpolation does. A convex effect does the inverse. And if you are not happy with linear interpolation, you can add a factor in the loop. This will be much faster than a Fourrier transform. To get a 3D effect, use a 3rd pass.

Comment: "So far?" We are talking about which method can resolve a problem, and, if possible, find the most efficient one. Bresenham will smoke the Fourrier transform every single time. To be more relevant than Bresenham, you will have to suggest a faster method.

Comment: A further explanation (as part of your answer) would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: The question is "I am looking for some algorithms", not for "some code". Further, I have a fulltime job. I posted a new solution below using a sin() table. Hope this will be more obvious how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

[CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) library has a fisheye sample, in examples\CImg_demo.cpp. The core algorithm seems very simple (and fast, as generally this library). I think it's an approximation of the real optical effect, but could be modified to handle the convex mirroring. I don't know if it could be extended to handle 'negative' curvature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `pre-calculated sin() table` and interpolate values to match the size of your bitmap. The inverse effect is achieved by either using an offset or a larger table.

Remembers me the (great times of the) DOS demos in the 80s...